# Subsequence in normed linear spaces

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, normed-spaces

Let $(x_n)$ be a sequence in a normed linear space $X$ with the following property:

For any subsequence $(x_{n_k})$ of $(x_n)$, there exists another subsequence $(x_{n_{k_l}})$ of $(x_{n_k})$ such that $(x_{n_{k_l}})$ converges to $x_0$.

Then show that $x_n\to x_0$.

Try: Suppose that $(x_n)$ is unbounded. Then there exists a subsequence $(x_{n_k})$ of $(x_n)$ such that $\|x_{n_k}\|\to \infty$. Thus, no subsequence of $(x_{n_k})$ can converge to $x_0$, a contradiction.

Therefore, $(x_n)$ is bounded. If possible suppose that $x_1\neq x_0$ is a subseuential limit of $(x_n)$. Then there exists a subsequence $(x_{n_k})$ of $(x_n)$ such that $x_{n_k}\to x_1$. Thus, no subsequence of $(x_{n_k})$ can converge to $x_0$, again a contradiction.

Therefore, every subsequential limit of $(x_n)$ is $x_0$. Thus, $x_n\to x_0$.

Is it correct? or I have made any mistake.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "Every subsequential limit of $(x_n)$ is $x_0$" does not imply that $x_n \to x_0$.  Consider for instance a Hilbert space with orthonormal basis $e_n$.  The sequence $e_1, 0, e_2, 0, e_3, 0, \dots$ has $0$ as its only subsequential limit, but it does not converge to 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proof has a gap at the end.  It is not sufficient to show that every subsequential limit of $(x_n)$ is $x_0$.  Consider for instance a Hilbert space with orthonormal basis $e_n$, and the sequence $(x_n) = (e_1, 0, e_2, 0, e_3, 0, \dots)$. Every convergent subsequence of $(x_n)$ has 0 as its limit, yet $(x_n)$ does not converge to 0.

Anyway, the bounded/unbounded distinction is not necessary.  Here's how I think about this: if you carefully negate the definition of sequence convergence, you can note that if $(x_n)$ does not converge to $x_0$, there must exist an open neighborhood $U$ of $x_0$ and a subsequence $(x_{n_k})$ in which all points are outside $U$.  If $(x_{n_k})$ has a further subsequence which converges to some point $y$, then $y$ must be outside $U$ and so it certainly cannot equal $x_0$.

Comment: I completely agree with your answer. My proof cannot go outside of finite-dimensional context. I will add an edit in context of your hint and complete the proof.